# Where to upload image for featured page on app store...?

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication

I have an app on app store and just wanted to check where to upload the image if my app is featured by app store.
For instance the attached image is a screenshot where cleartrip is a featured app in the travel section and it has big image shown on the top (annotated image.) 
Now my app is also visible in the featured page but not at the top.

Comment: I hear Apple will contact you asking for high resolution image assets if they choose to feature your app.

Comment: Can you quote your source from somewhere..?

Comment: "Each Thursday afternoon, a small editorial team at Apple selects apps to highlight for the following week in the App Store. Like the rest of Apple, this team operates secretively and rarely reaches out to notify the developers, except to occasionally ask for artwork or, for very high-profile selections like the end-of-year picks, to give a heads up so the companies can make sure they're ready for a significant increase in activity."   http://mashable.com/2014/01/03/apple-app-store-features/#W3uH1GzQqGqK

Comment: Your question is not related to the programming, you'd better ask it somewhere else.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava also this website has a screenshot of the message: http://john.do/featured/  the screenshot:  http://john.do/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/promotional-artwork.png

Comment: @Zhang can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear Apple will contact you asking for image assets if they choose to feature your app.

Some confirmations from others:

"Each Thursday afternoon, a small **editorial team at Apple** selects apps to highlight for the following week in the App Store. Like the rest of Apple, this team operates secretively and rarely reaches out to notify the developers, except to occasionally **ask for artwork** or, for very high-profile selections like the end-of-year picks, to give a heads up so the companies can make sure they're ready for a significant increase in activity."

http://mashable.com/2014/01/03/apple-app-store-features/#W3uH1GzQqGqK

and

From John Saddington's website (http://john.do/featured/), a screenshot of Apple's email when featured asking for artwork:

http://john.do/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/promotional-artwork.png